# on button click export to csv using devexpress xtragrid

Tags: csv, devexpress, export-to-csv, xtragrid

I m using devxtra grid control and devexpress xtra bar.What i want to do is

1) I have a button on the bar which should select all the rows in the grid and then export to csv.
I m using Itemclick event and in that i m using gridView1.SelectAll() but in the output nothing is being selected.

****************************Designer*********************************

```
           // barButtonSelectAll

        // 
        this.barButtonSelectAll.Caption = "Select All";
        this.barButtonSelectAll.Id = 1;
        //this.barButtonSelectAll.Glyph = true;
        this.barButtonSelectAll.Width = 50;
   this.barButtonSelectAll.LargeGlyph=global::Binder.Resources.close_16;
        this.barButtonSelectAll.Name = "barButtonSelectAll";
        this.barButtonSelectAll.ItemClick+=newDevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventHandler(this.barButtonSelectAll_ItemClick);
        //  

            // gridControl1
        // 
        this.gridControl1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.gridControl1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.gridControl1.MainView = this.gridView1;
        this.gridControl1.MenuManager = this.barCopyResult;
        this.gridControl1.Name = "gridControl1";
        this.gridControl1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(922, 441);
        this.gridControl1.TabIndex = 4;
        this.gridControl1.ViewCollection.AddRange(new DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.BaseView[] {
        this.gridView1});
        // 
        // gridView1
        // 
        this.gridView1.GridControl = this.gridControl1;
        this.gridView1.Name = "gridView1";
        this.gridView1.OptionsView.ShowGroupPanel = false;
        //
```

****************************Code*********************************

```
 private void barButtonSelectAll_ItemClick (object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        //StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("D:\\gridview.csv");
        //for (int i = 0; i < gridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
        //{
    //sw.Write(gridView1.Columns[i].AppearanceHeader.TextOptions.ToString());
        //  if (i != gridView1.Columns.Count)
        //  {
        //      sw.Write(",");
        //  }
        //  sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
        //  foreach( GridViewRow dr in gridView1.RowCount)
        //}
        gridView1.SelectAll();
        for (int i = 0; i < gridView1.RowCount; i++)
        {
            //gridView1.GetDetailView(1,1);
            gridControl1.ExportToCsv("D:\\csv docs");
        }
        //MessageBox.Show("Hola");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, check the [GridView.OptionsSelection.MultiSelect](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnViewOptionsSelection_MultiSelecttopic) property because If this property is set to `false`, the [GridView.SelectAll](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_SelectAlltopic) method **does nothing**.

At second, to export all the data displayed by the GridControl's view to the specified file in `CSV` format you should not select something in this view. And moreover, you should not do call this method in cycle for each row.
Just use the following code:

```
void barButtonExport_Click(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e) {
    gridView1.ExportToCsv(@"D:\csv docs\1.csv");
}
```

Remarks:
The [ExportToCsv](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseBaseView_ExportToCsvtopic1166) method indirectly calls the [DevExpress.XtraPrinting.PrintingSystemBase.ExportToCsv](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraPrintingPrintingSystemBase_ExportToCsvtopic) method of the XtraPrinting Library. If this library is not available, the method does nothing.

For general information on exporting data in the GridControl refer to [Export Overview](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument995).